# Facebook App Event log custom JSON for messenger bot

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger-bot

I have a messenger bot that I want to add Facebook analytics on. I am using app event api to log custom events as seen [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/bots-for-messenger#event-example).

In my facebook event I want to log my class as JSON so I can export that JSON from the Facebook Event Viewer to a file and use that file to do some analytics on what the users are requesting. I don't know if this is possible so I tested using fb_content based from the [event api docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/app-event-api/).

Using the graph explorer I tried to log my custom JSON like this:

[image]

When I looked at the Event Viewer I don't have the JSON that I logged. Is it possible to get the JSON that I log?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should add all the keys you want to track inside `custom_events`, then you will be able to view the values inside Facebook Analytics's Event Debugging section

Comment: Hi @tremonti92 yup you are correct. That is what I did in the graph explorer above. In my second screenshot I showed that no values were saved in fb.

Answer (score 0):

As of 10/20/2017, the docs are wrong. `page_scoped_user_id:` should be `senderId` not `recipientId`

Answer (score 0):

In your actual code, if you are using Node JS, you can make a method to log the events and call it from all the places where you need it.
You can check the following page for more info with the code and output.
https://apiai-aws-heroku-nodejs-bots.blogspot.com/2017/11/how-much-was-conversion-by-your-bot.html

Comment: you should use the answer to only answer the question you will be eligible to comment on the posts once you get past 50 repute